# Java - Pass a method to a class and execute it in a new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

**[Check the bottom of the question for updates]**

As in the title, I'd like to write a class which takes in a method and executes it in a new Thread. I lurked around SO and came up with something like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MyExecutor<T> implements Runnable{

    private Callable<T> method;


    public <T> MyExecutor(Callable<T> pMethod){
        this.method = pMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // start a new Thread, then
            method.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed calling method "+method.getClass());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

However Eclipse warns me that, inside the constructor, in

```
this.method = pMethod;
```

I `cannot convert from Callable <T> to Callable <T>`.

It smells like I'm doing something entirely wrong, but I can't grasp it.

**UPDATE**

Turns out I was reinventing the wheel, what I wanted to do can be attained like this:

```
public class MyExecutor implements Executor{


    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        new Thread(command).start();
    }

}
```

In the main flow a method can be executed in a new thread like this:

```
    MyExecutor myExec = new MyExecutor();

    myExec.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myMethod();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can't pass methods to other classes. you can pass instances of methods on which you can call methods

Comment: Did you try removing <T> in front of the constructor?

Comment: The `<T>` before your constructor is declaring a second generic type, also called `T`. If you remove it, your code should be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you added a type parameter `<T>` to your constructor, it shadows the type parameter for the class. Therefore, the `T` for the constructor argument `pMethod` is a different `T` than the class parameter, which is what Eclipse is warning you about. Just change the signature for the constructor to `public MyExecutor(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. Since we're here, does the idea itself (passing a method to the class, creating a thread inside my generic class and executing my method) make sense? Is it decent practice? Marked as the solution anyway.

Comment: @Tom You're reinventing the wheel basically. The JDK already has executors, that provide you with the functionality (and more, with `Future` and other such things). At least you know that your idea is valid enough to include in the runtime ;)

Comment: As Kayaman says - not only is it valid practice, it's already done. You might want to look into the `java.util.concurrent.Executor` hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you all, every day is a school day :)

Comment: @Tom, you aren't passing a method.  You are passing an _object_ that implements the `Callable` interface.  Java does not have functional types.  Java8 fakes them with `@Functional` interfaces.